# Capture VSCode Intellisense

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, intellisense, vscode-extensions

I am currently working on a VSCode extension, and I would like to utilize the abilities of Intellisense (Pylance in this case) to help with a feature in my extension. I simply want to capture the output of Pylance so I can pass it as an argument into a VSCode extension function. I am unsure how it would be possible to capture Intellisense output. Another interesting question would be whether it is possible to alter Intellisense output directly: could you adjust how Intellisense is displayed with a VSCode extension?

In short: Is it possible to capture Intellisense output and/or alter Intellisense output is displayed using a VSCode extension?

Comment: Capture: No, Display: you might try MarkDown

Comment: If you read the end user license agreement of Pylance, you will see it is a lot different from other extensions (like the open source ones), so you'd better avoid anything like described above as it can be seen as violations of the license agreement "SCOPE OF LICENSE" https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items/ms-python.vscode-pylance/license

Comment: BTW, if you want to somehow control Python intellisense, you can build your own upon Pyright, https://github.com/microsoft/pyright It shares some code with Pylance, but it probably won't offer the same results.